# Unregistered to ObservableCollection PropertyChangedEventHandler is needed?

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

I have this `ObservableCollection<MyData>` that holds my objects and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged interface`.

And notice this property changes:

```
private int _files;

public int Files
{
    get { return _files; }
    set
    {
        _files= value;
        NotifyPropertyChange("Files");
    }
}

public virtual void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

So after my object finished it's work i need to `Unregistered` to `PropertyChangedEventHandler`  ?

Comment: what would be the use case ?

Comment: What do you mean  the use case ?

Comment: why do you want to Unregister `PropertyChangedEventHandler`

Comment: I just ask if i need to do that after finish my work

Comment: No need to unregister it.